# Bridge user sessions across two wordpress installs?

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies

I'm having some issues sharing the user sessions across two installs.

(a) site on http://stolenmx.com (b) site on http://arcade.stolenmx.com

I have installed B in the same database as A and I have defined the user and user_meta tables so I am sharing user data and users etc but I can't seem to bridge the sessions.

I have tried using cookies a few different ways but nothing works.

This is what I'm using in (b) wp-config at the moment with no effect,

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.stolenmx.com');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
```

does anyone know how to get this working?

I'm actually using UserPro on site (a) to manage registration and login and I have wp-login.php disabled. Could this be why cookie isn't working cause UserPro saves the cookie elsewhere or just simply doesn't use one?

Comment: Have you tried `stolenmx.com` or `.stolenmx.com` so both domains are matched? I'd have thought specifying a 'www' prefix would match neither. I expect the syntax is the same as for [`setcookie()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: Yeah, I actually just tried both but nothing happens, It has no effect to either site.

Comment: Have you checked the cookie validity of the cookies produced in your browser? Depending on your browser you may be able to do it natively, or need a plugin.

Comment: Hey i have no idea how to do that? What would i be looking for?

Comment: It's usually in a cookies dialogue box, often on a browser menu or in an options panel. I am sure you can find it! - and if you can't, don't be afraid to search for "<browser> cookies window" or similar in a search engine. Firefox on Ubuntu can do this natively, just checked - expect it is the same for Firefox on all platforms.

Comment: According to firefox stolenmx.com isn't storing any cookies on my computer?

Comment: OK, that's useful to know. Is that the case even if you log into your WordPress site? I should imagine it would be impossible to record logon state information if cookies are not working at all.

Comment: Yeah that's even when logged in =(

Comment: If you can't see your cookies but your login is working fine, I think something is very wrong. Login in WordPress works on cookies - there is no other mainstream mechanism that persists state. Perhaps try another browser? Have you disabled cookies in this browser?

Comment: Hey yeah I had disabled the cookies on firefox.. It's enabled now and it say's the cookie is there, pdb-wp_session but it isn't working as it should?

Comment: Okay, so I now have it working ALMOST lol I had to define the MD5 COOKEHASK. The only problem I have now is that when I log out from site (b) it doesn't log out from site (a)! 

login works so if i login to site (a) it logs in to (b) and vice versa, and If i logout from site (a) it logs me out from site (b) it's only when I log out from (b) it doesn't log me out from (a)? 

Make sense? lol

Comment: Err... might be worth updating your question, and do make it as detailed as possible. It may be worth re-checking the domain validity of your cookies again, and adding that information to your question.

Comment: I will do mate, Thanks.